# Django: Internationalization of urls and models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-parler

I'm working on a little website that should be in Spanish and English.

I've spent hours reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.conf.urls.i18n) and well, I'm ok with it. Also, I think I'm gonna be using [Django-parler](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler) to do the `model internationalization` but I've never use internationalization with Django let alone django-parser and I have a couple of questions.

How does Django-parler works in the django-admin? It says: "**Nice admin integration.**"

Does Django-parler chose the right language in the model from the i18n_patterns?

I would really love if you'd put together the simplest of example for this. I'm really struggling with this. Thanks in advance.

PS. I chose `django-parler` cause of a recommendation in freenode #django. I'm not married to django-parler. What I want is to internationalize the templates (django provides that) and to be able to internationalize the model content from django admin.

Comment: take a look of `django-modeltranslation` http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, which I have integrated it to my project perfectly. it is simple, elegant, well-documented.  you just need to defined an extra model translation definition file, and `modeltranslation` will do the rest for you. it worths to have a try.

Comment: @Enix thanks so much for your comment. At the very end I decided to go with django-parler and pretty much I did a good job at putting things together. It works like a charm. Thanks tho, I appreciate your contribution :)